# Comparing INT_MAX and long giving wrong result

Tags: c

I am getting long from user input (with `fgets()` and converting to long with `strtoul()`), but when testing it to convert into integer giving wrong result.

Declarations:

```
char buf[BUFSIZE];
unsigned char input[80];
int done = 0;
int i, val;
long valPrimary;
char *ptr;
```

Code:

```
 // gets the max first 79 characters, whichever comes first
 if (fgets(input, INPUTSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
        printf("Input ok\n");
 } else {
    printf("Input not ok\n");
    return 0;
 }

// get unsigned long from input
valPrimary = strtoul(input, &ptr, 10);      

// Check if any character was converted 
if (ptr == input) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't convert string to number\n");
    return 0;
}       

if ((valPrimary == LONG_MAX || valPrimary == LONG_MIN) && errno== ERANGE) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Number out of range for LONG\n");      
    return 0;
}    
printf("valPrimary: %lu\n", valPrimary);
printf("Max Int: %i\n", INT_MAX);
printf("Min Int: %i\n", INT_MIN);
printf("Long size: %lu\n", sizeof(long));

// Check overflows and if long is convertable to int
if ( (valPrimary > INT_MAX) || (valPrimary < INT_MIN) ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Number out of range for INT\n");
    return 0;
} else {
    val = (int) valPrimary;
}
```

For example if I enter some a very big number, I am getting this kind of stdout:

> valPrimary: 18446744073709551615
>
> Max Int: 2147483647

But error message is not displayed and conversion still happens.

Comment: If `valPrimary` is an unsigned long, how could it be smaller than `INT_MIN` that is negative ?

Comment: Is `sizeof(long) == 8` on your platform? I just tested the code with `unsigned long long` and it works. Also, you probably got a warning for comparing signed and unsigned types.

Comment: @Quentin that is right, but I still should see the error message because of the first part of if statement.

Comment: I cannot repeat this with `ull` (as mtijancic wrote). Are you sure that `long` is not 32 bit on your platform? (although, in that case `printf("%lu", valPrimary);` would also fail, which is weird)

Comment: @mtijanic yes sizeof(long) is 8 on my platform, but I am not getting error/warning when comparing signed and unsigned types.

Comment: This is really strange. Could you give a full example, along with declarations for `val` and `valPrimary`. Also, could you try with assigning the value directly and not through `fgets`/`strtoul`?

Comment: I have updated the code with full example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect mixing of `signed long` and `strtoul()`.  Use `strtol()`.  [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233393/quentin)
`strtoul("18446744073709551615",...)` --> `ULONG_MAX` and that converted to `long` likely becomes `-1`.

```
long valPrimary;
...
// valPrimary = strtoul(input, &ptr, 10);      
valPrimary = strtol(input, &ptr, 10);      
...
if ((valPrimary == LONG_MAX || valPrimary == LONG_MIN) && errno== ERANGE) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Number out of range for LONG\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, what is happening is this:

valPrimary is declared as:
`long valPrimary;`
rather than:
`unsigned long valPrimary`

The decimal value `18446744073709551615` corresponds to hexadecimal value `0xffffffffffffffff`.

When this value is stored in a signed long, the first bit is the sign bit. In fact, `0xffffffffffffffff` in a signed long is equal to `-1`.

Hece, the conversion is made, and `-1` is returned, since INT_MAX > -1 > INT_MIN